# Changing the Team Site Template

Tags: 2010, site-template

Is it possible to change the settings on an existing site template, such as the team site?

We would like to recommend to our users to create sites using the team site template where possible, however we would like versioning to be automatically set. 
I realise we could save our own site as a template and have them use this, however this puts this site at the bottom of the "Create" list, which isnt ideal from a usability point of view. 
Can we edit the team site template, or reorder the create list to show our custom template at the top?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the order or pick the web templates you wan to be shown in the create list.

Go to "Site Actions" -> "Site Settings" -> under "Look and Feel" choose "Page layouts and site templates". in the Subsite Templates choose "Subsites can only use the following site templates" and pick and order your web templates

[image]